# Android Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used

Tags: php, android, webview, upload

I've made an Android application with GCM and a webview. Now I made an image upload on the website and if I fire the file upload i get the following message:

```
03-31 10:27:16.185 553-592/webdesign.jk.elevent I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
```

The app opens the gallery succesfully and I'm able to choose a image to upload. After choosing a image and I go back to the app, the app is closed and I think it's everytime I get the alert about the Tag Manager. While I don't use the Tag Manager.

Is there somebody who knows a soluition for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my code the tag name was **"TAG"** and I got this message .

```
Log.i("TAG", "gallary");
```

I convert it to another name as follows and it works for me:

```
Log.i("name", "gallary");
```